# Cannot select window color theme after upgrade from 18.04 to 20.04

Tags: themes, 20.04, icon-themes

[image: Appearance dialog]

After upgrading Ubuntu from version 18.04 LTS to 20.04 LTS some icons have not changed to the new version and window color themes are not selectable.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I saw the problem too, after upgrade from 18.04 to 20.04.

Installing the Yaru theme packages can fix it.

```
sudo apt install yaru-theme-gtk yaru-theme-sound yaru-theme-gnome-shell yaru-theme-icon yaru-theme-unity
```

Comment: Working find thank you so much